# OAuth2 Playground - Problem with authentication (Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch) when entering my Client Id and Secret

Tags: oauth2-playground

I have a problem presented because I want me and my development team to test the GET of the review list to implement it on our site. The first problem is that when we use in the OAuth2 Playground page the uri of "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage" authorizing it and testing it, it tells us: "PERMISSION_DENIED" to which, later, we test entering the following configuration:
[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Kvg.png)

Which, when authorizing the API in step 1 tells us:

> You cannot access because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later or contact the developer about this problem. More information about this error
> If you are a developer of this app, consult the error details.
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch